# JS function result not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mithril.js

I'm trying to render the result of the function `renderVerticalCards`, but nothing is returned in the DOM, other than the outer `divs` (those from outside the function call). I have confirmed through the console, that the function is being called, so I'm guessing that my problem has to do with my use of curly brackets, but I have not been able to find a solution. Any suggestions?

```
    view({ attrs }) {

        console.log("In view", attrs);
        console.log(attrs);
        
        const renderVerticalCards = (cards) => {
            console.log("in function")
            return(
                cards.map(card => {
                <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-4-phone mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-3-tablet mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-4-desktop process-card">
                    <div class="process-card__number-container">
                        <div class="process-card__number-container__circle">
                            <div class="process-card__number-container__circle process-card__number-container__circle__number"> {card.Number} </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class=".tk-typography--title-md process-card__title"> {card.Title} </div>
                    <div class="mdc-typography--body preserve-linebreaks process-card__text"> {card.ContentText} </div>
                    <a class="mdc-button process-card__link" href={card.Link}> {card.LinkText} </a>  
                </div>
                })
            )
        }

        return (
            <div class="mdc-layout-grid" style="padding-top:0">
                <div class="mdc-layout-grid__inner">
                { renderVerticalCards(this.cards) }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: The map function doesn't return anything.

Comment: @GuyIncognito  Brilliant, it's so obvious now, but I was totally blind to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
cards.map(card => {
return (
                    <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-4-phone mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-3-tablet mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-4-desktop process-card">
                        <div class="process-card__number-container">
                            <div class="process-card__number-container__circle">
                                <div class="process-card__number-container__circle process-card__number-container__circle__number"> {card.Number} </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class=".tk-typography--title-md process-card__title"> {card.Title} </div>
                        <div class="mdc-typography--body preserve-linebreaks process-card__text"> {card.ContentText} </div>
                        <a class="mdc-button process-card__link" href={card.Link}> {card.LinkText} </a>  
                    </div>
);
                    })
```